# count occurrence of xml child nodes from two identical parent nodes

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to count the number child nodes within two identical parent nodes in an XML clob that I've stored in a table of mine.

The XML Clob has a format like this:

```
<ProductS>
<id>1</id>
<Discount></Discount>
<Discount></Discount>
</ProductS>
<ProductS>
<id>2</id>
<Discount></Discount>
</ProductS>
```

I want my xmlquery to go through this XML clob and identify how many Discounts there are in each ProductS and IGNORE those that have less or zero `<Discount>`.
So in the example above it should return 2.

Thanks.

Comment: check this site ... it will help you 
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2433392

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that my answer is for SQL-SERVER only. I'll let it here in case this help other people

Here is a Query that will get you 1 record for **each product with 1 or more Discount node**. This is done by using the xml query function "**count()**"

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '<ProductS>
<id>1</id>
<Discount></Discount>
<Discount></Discount>
</ProductS>
<ProductS>
<id>2</id>
<Discount></Discount>
</ProductS>'


select 
    n.xmlNode.query('.') ProductNode    
from @xml.nodes('/ProductS') n(xmlNode)
where 
    n.xmlNode.query('count(Discount)').value('.','int') > 0
```